# RHEL 7.6 "Authentication is required to run add-password"

Tags: authentication

I am getting this authentication window whenever I logon. I am not sure what it is, and how to get rid of it. Any ideas?

[image: Authentication window]

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I had a samba kvm update running, so whenever I resumed it, add-password function was called, and that required authentication since my user did not belong to the group allowed to run it.